# magento migration tool migrate:data errors

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

When I run migrate:data I get some errors, any way to fix this?

```
[2017-03-06 17:00:38][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_CATALOG_COMPARE_ITEM_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID) constraint fails. Orphan records id: 0 from `catalog_compare_item`.`customer_id` has no referenced records in `customer_entity`
[2017-03-06 17:00:38][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_CATALOG_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) constraint fails. Orphan records id: 903 from `catalog_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`
[2017-03-06 17:00:38][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID) constraint fails. Orphan records id: 903 from `catalog_product_entity_int`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`
[2017-03-06 17:00:38][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID) constraint fails. Orphan records id: 19,21 from `eav_attribute`.`entity_type_id` has no referenced records in `eav_entity_type`
[2017-03-06 17:00:38][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_EAV_ATTR_SET_ENTT_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID) constraint fails. Orphan records id: 19,21 from `eav_attribute_set`.`entity_type_id` has no referenced records in `eav_entity_type`
[2017-03-06 17:00:38][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) constraint fails. Orphan records id: 202,213,706,732,903,2712 from `eav_entity_attribute`.`attribute_id` has no referenced records in `eav_attribute`
```

and this is another one

```
[2017-03-06 17:00:42][ERROR]: Source documents are not mapped: paybox_question_number,strikeiron_tax_rate
```

Answer (score 3):

First problem: **Foreign key (fk_...) constraint fails. Orphan records id: ...**

What does it mean?

- You have orphan records in your database. This means that a foreign key is referencing another item which doens't exist anymore. Check some SQL-Tutorials or documentation to read more about it.

How to solve it:

- Delete all rows with orphan records or correct all missing data. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445966/elegant-way-to-remove-orphan-rows)

Second problem: **Source documents are not mapped**

What does it mean?

- (*I'm not complete sure about this, probably correction needed*): You have had different tables that are no more the same, but in a way that the migration tool can't recognize it, as they are customized or extended tables. So in that case you have to check manually whether you want or need to migrate that data aswell or exclude it.

How to solve it:

- Check the documentation about mapping, if you want to migrate this data. (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html)
- You can exclude these like shown in this case study example: (http://oyenetwork.com/articles/data-migration-to-magento2-case-study/)

Comment: for orphan records can I just delete that products content field?  do you know if it is a attribute or what?

Comment: It would probably solve that problem. Take care and backup first. 
1: No referenced customer_entity with that id, so no referenced customer
2/3/6: No referenced attribute
4/5: No referenced entity type

Other solution would be to check whats missing and reproduce that through SQL commands

Comment: if I add ignore in map.xml I still get the error because "paybox_question_number,strikeiron_tax_rate" only exists in magento 1.6.2.0 and I upgraded to 1.9.2.2 some time ago

Comment: There are different of these files which are used. Check which one is needed, maybe it's another... But I'm not sure whether this solves your problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to the issues section of the data migration tool Github, the official solution is there : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/migration/migration-troubleshooting.html